# Location descriptions showing up in wrong place for ArcGIS Online Story Maps?

Tags: arcgis-online, story-map

I've created a story map tour to use for an app created through Esri's app builder tool and am currently experiencing some issues with both. There seems to be a glitch where the description and title for one location in the story map will be copied to another location. For instance, location x's description and title will appear for both location x and location y. I've found I can temporarily fix the story map by reuploading the csv file but this does not fix it in the app based off of the story map.